# Calendar not closing when click outside

Tags: jquery, ipad, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code for datepicker:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/Content/images/calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText:"Calendar",
        beforeShow: function (textbox, instance) {
            instance.dpDiv.css({
                marginTop: (-textbox.offsetHeight) + 'px',
                marginLeft: textbox.offsetWidth + 'px'
            });
        },
        minDate: 0
    });
```

The problem in that on iPad (on Galaxy Tab all works fine) when click outsite of calendar it not closing. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try setting properties of UIPicker as "setHidden:YES"